# Laravel after upgrade, .env variable Undefined index

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, laravel-upgrade

I'm upgrading Laravel to 5.2 from 5.1. When i refere to variable API_DOMAIN in .env file using $_ENV 
`$_ENV['API_DOMAIN']`
I get an error saying Undefined index: API_DOMAIN". Am I missing something here? should i do something after composer update?

Comment: According to the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) *If you are using the `config:cache` command during deployment, you must make sure that you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.* This also applies to using `$_ENV` since they both read from the same source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the env helper instead, `env('API_DOMAIN')`

Answer (score 2):

Run the below commands after making changes in **env** file. It will flush and repopulate all the **env** variable.

```
php artisan config:cache   //flush all cached env variable
php artisan config:clear   //repopulate all the env variable
php artisan cache:clear    //flush all the cached content
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not directly work with environment values in your application, I would create a new configuration file or use an existing one and add the value there, this way you can cache the configuration.

Lets use your `API_DOMAIN` as an example:

**.env file**

```
API_DOMAIN=www.mydomain.com
```

**Config file**

`config/api.php` for example

```
<?php

return [
    'domain' => env('API_DOMAIN'),
];
```

Now you can use the [config helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#accessing-configuration-values) to use this variable in your application:

```
$value = config('api.domain');
```

You should never use the `env()` helper outside of config files, because when you cache your config, `env()` will return `null`.